# How can I partially specialize a existing template class into a new type?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, partial-specialization

----IMPORTANT: This is not a solution for a partial template specialisation but rather I was looking for a type alias without knowing it. Sorry for the confusion-----

### What I want to do

I want to specialize boost::unordered_multimap to essentially only require the data that will be stored and therefore make the key permanentally a boost::uuids::uuid.

### Current attempt

```
template<class t>
boost::unordered_multimap<boost::uuids::uuid, t, boost::hash<boost::uuids::uuid>> unorderedUUIDMultMap;'

    Here is the usage:
        unorderedUUIDMultMap<int> uuidMultMap; //Should create a mutlimap storing ints.
```

Here is the error:

```
main.cpp|24|error: expected ';' before 'uuidMultMap'|
```

I also tried to use "typedef" before template but that also didnt work out.

How can I properly do this simple shortcut?

Comment: you want `template <typename T> using my_mmap = boost::unordered_multimap<boost::uuids::uuid, T, boost::hash<boost::uuids::uuid>>;` This is also known as type alias. What you're doing is very far from partial specialization.

Comment: @Incomputable Should I edit the title and replace partial specialization with type alias to remove confusion?

Comment: @Incomputable Please also post as an answer so I can tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not a partial specialization, but template type alias:

```
template <typename T> using my_mmap = boost::unordered_multimap<boost::uuids::uuid, T, boost::hash<boost::uuids::uuid>>;
```